# React app on cloud run with GCP IAM to connect with backend REST API on cloud run

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-run, google-iam

I have a react application which is authenticated by google IAM. But I am not able to use the JWT token to access the backend REST API on a gcp cloud run. However with a token manually generated like gcloud auth print-identity-token is able to access the rest API.

Authentication with GCP generates an auth token and the same token should be able to connect with backend API in cloud run.

```
 import { useGoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';
 const handleGoogleLogin = useGoogleLogin({
 scope: google.scope,....})
```

Response:

```
access_token: "ya29.a0AeTM1ieQABEf023ELeFTMXNyG322M_m5oKheJrCRkmms92ilXeITOiFp1hSV7Cz0Fsb1pMvdnSdzooq5Ls1fr2MCWUN6rLNN3YQj masked"
authuser: "1"
expires_in: 3598
hd: "company.com"
prompt: "none"
scope: "email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-identity.devices.lookup https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-identity.groups https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-identity.groups.readonly openid"
token_type: "Bearer"
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Cannot access the backend rest api hosted on gcp cloud run which has authentication enabled. from a react app which is again on a cloud run but authenticated by GCP IAM

Comment: Edit your question including code, error messages, etc. What type of token are you using, etc.

Comment: Can you share how you generate the auth token for now?

Comment: Cloud Run requires an OIDC Identity Token for authentication. Your code does not show what type of token you are creating or how you are using it. My guess is that you are using an OAuth Access Token. Edit your question and include the details requested.